# Are multi-region networks more likely to experience a partition than single region networks?

Tags: networking, tcp, distributed-computing, partition, distributed-system

The [first fallacy of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing) is making the assumption that networks are reliable.

Consider two scenarios:

Scenario 1: TCP communication in us-east-1(same AZ).

Scenario 2: TCP communication between us-east and us-west.

In both scenarios Servers A and B communicate via a reliable protocol like TCP. In both cases a network partition is possible. Scenario 1 could be caused by networking issues in the datacenter. Scenario 2 could experience a network partition in the same way as Scenario 1 as well as via any sort of networking issues that occur in transit between us-east and us-west

Consider failure as server A unable to receive a response from B in some bounded time limit, say 1 minute. My question is: are requests in Scenario 2 more likely to fail — via a network partition or other networkings issues  — than scenario 1? Is making the assumption that requests will succeed in scenario 1 *more often* than scenario 2 a bad assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Probability(**P**) of a network partition is proportional to a failure of every individual component in your network (not accounting simultaneous failures for simplicity's sake)

As you have mentioned, in the first case 
*P_partition1 ~ P_failure_your_datacenter*, in the second case *P_partition2 ~ P_failure_your_datacenter + P_failure_in_transit*

Given that *P_failure_in_transit > 0* seems that  *P_partition_2 > P_partition_1*

So I'd say you've already answered your own question.
A related question that's worth answering is *how much likely is it?* It is far more complex and can only be answered analyzing the real-world stats - your own or coming from your hosting provider